# Laptop suspends every 30 seconds after lid close and re-open

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management, laptop, vaio

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Sony Vaio VGN-CR120E. I did a clean install recently from a usb stick, removing the previous operating system.

When I close the lid on the laptop, it suspends properly, and when I re-open it, it requires my password, as I have specified in the system settings. But it keeps going back to suspend without prompting, usually about every 30 seconds, until and unless I restart the system.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Go into power options in settings and choose 'Do nothing' in 'When i close the lid' option. In the brightness option turn off lock. After doing these changes it wont suspend

Comment: I want the laptop to suspend when I close the lid. I just want it to not suspend every 30 seconds after I open it back up. In other words, I want it to work the way it is supposed to work.